# Arduino Pro Mini lower BOD problem

Tags: arduino-pro-mini, avrdude, isp, arduinoisp

I am planing to build a project where an arduino pro mini 3.3V runs on 2 aa batteries. The standard brown out detection shuts it down at about 2.7/2.8V where it could run on lower voltages too.
So I changed the efuse to get the BOD down to 1.8V. I connected a serial to usb converter and used avrdude:

```
avrdude -c avrisp -p m328p -P COM5 -b 19200 -U lfuse:w:0xff:m -U hfuse:w:0xda:m -U efuse:w:0x06:m
```

Then I tried to upload a program using the arduino 1.0.3 IDE but I got this error:

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x1c
```

With 1.6.4 I got another error:

```
    avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x75
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x1c
```

After some googling I tried some lower baud rate (the standard seems to be 57600). With 19200 everything worked with avrdude, so I created a new entry in the boards.txt

```
    ##############################################################

pro328.name=Arduino Pro or Pro Mini (3.3V, 8 MHz) w/ ATmega328 BOD 1.8V

pro328.upload.protocol=arduino
pro328.upload.maximum_size=30720
pro328.upload.speed=19200

pro328.bootloader.low_fuses=0xFF
pro328.bootloader.high_fuses=0xDA
pro328.bootloader.extended_fuses=0x06
pro328.bootloader.path=atmega
pro328.bootloader.file=ATmegaBOOT_168_atmega328_pro_8MHz.hex
pro328.bootloader.unlock_bits=0x3F
pro328.bootloader.lock_bits=0x0F

pro328.build.mcu=atmega328p
pro328.build.f_cpu=8000000L
pro328.build.core=arduino
pro328.build.variant=standard
```

And burned a bootloader using the 1.0.3 IDE again. After that I could upload a blink program. My goal is to upload a mysensors sketch though and that doesn't work. I am getting an error

```
avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0002
         0x69 != 0x61
avrdude: verification error; content mismatch
```

Mysensors seems to have general problems with old arduino IDEs so I tried to use the newer 1.6.4 but I can't define my own board there and if I try it without I get hte out of sync error (because it's still using the wrong baudrate I guess).

I also tried using another arduino uno as ISP => same results

How can I fix this? Is there a way to define my own board for 1.6.x?
Whats the standard way of doing this and why does the change of the efuse results in me not beeing able to program the mini any longer?

Thanks for every answer/help!

Answer (score 1):

When you go below (or above) the manufacturer's voltage/clock specifications, expect some problems. One chip may work another will not.  Remember the lower the voltage normally the slower the clock needs to be.  The CPUs are cut from a wafer (size and geometry specific) which may contain many thousand CPU die, they are at different locations on the wafer they will be a little different and they make more then one wafer.

Check the data sheet, it will show what clock speed will work at what voltage.  As the CPU clock changes so will your baud rate so plan on recalculating that if you change the clock. Example:  If you are operating with a 16MHz clock and change it to 8MHz the baud will be exactly 1/2.  If at 9600 it will be 4800 unless you modify the clock dividers.

Your error indicates a potential baud rate problem. One of the funny things that happens when the voltage is above/below the manufacturer's speck not all instructions operate properly over temperature. Clock problems should be expected.